# Places near which there are no buildings

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I want to find all `place=village` with no buildings near them. Right now the query looks like this:

```
area
  ["boundary"="administrative"]
  ["name"="Липецкая область"]
->.b;

(
  node(area.b)
    ["place"~"village"];
)->.c;

(
  way[building](around.c:500)->.build; // <- !
) -> .build;

(
  node(around.build:500)
    ["place"~"village"];
) -> .d;

(.c; - .d;)->.result;

.result out center;
```

But on large areas the script is slow. I know roughly what can be improved.

The line with `<- !` selects **all** buildings near the place. But it needs to be at **least one** building. But how do I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "large area" and "slow"? Can you be a bit more specific what you mean by it? Does "large" refer to the exact query you've posted, or for something else?

Comment: I want to run a query for a region with a larger area and expand the place type, but this causes the script to take a long time to run.

Comment: I asked specifically for an example of a larger area (i.e. a concrete bounding box or relation), and the actual runtime. Can you provide those details?

Comment: Region: `"name"="Смоленская область"`
Places: `"place"~"hamlet|village"`
https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1abr runtime error: Query timed out in "query" at line 16 after 184 seconds.

Comment: You can increase the timeout value to make the query finish successfully. Other than that, there's no way for you to improve the query at the moment. https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1ach

Comment: What if we try using the `foreach` operator? Suppose we can't make the query stop at the first result we find. Can we leave only the first result? Something like this: ```foreach -> .c (
  way[building](around.c:1000)->.build // and get(0) somehow get the first element
)```

Comment: You can't stop `foreach` after the first element, and iterating over thousands of nodes will for sure be painfully slow. There's a reason why I said there's no way for you to optimize it. On a more recent Overpass branch, your query takes 2s, so this is more an issue of the internal implementation.

Comment: I don't want to stop `foreach`. Also, I realized that there is no parameter like maxsize, so that overpass doesn't do extra work. But I want to keep only one building at each iteration (i.e. for each village), not all buildings nearby. That is, I want to take the first element of the array on this line. `way[building](around.c:1000){some operator for get first element}->.build` Is it possible?

Comment: Well, you can keep the way with the lowest id in each iteration, but that doesn't help much in terms of performance. It will be at least 10 times slower compared to what you have right now: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1avr

Comment: Realized that I actually already in the loop can form the result and the query managed to fit into a few lines: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1axR But unfortunately ~x1.5 times slower.  I tried to get rid of combining sets(https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1axS), but for some reason filtering stopped working.